# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function rowCount() on boolean

Tags: php

Как пофиксить данную ошибку
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function rowCount() on boolean

Отрывок кода

```
 <?php
            //подключаемся к СУБД 
            $db = Db::getConnection();

            $part = $_GET['part'];
            if ($part=="all")
            {
//строим запрос для выбора продуктов, их производителей и отдела, в котором они продаются
                $sql = 'SELECT product.nazv, product.price, product.srok, proizv.nazv, proizv.sity, otdel.otdel, product.idp FROM product, proizv, otdel WHERE proizv.idpr = product.idpr AND otdel.ido = proizv.ido LIMIT 0,1000 ';
//выполняем запрос
                $result = $db->query($sql);
//проверяем количество выбранных записей, если 0 – выводим сообщение о том, что записей нет, если > 0 – выводим их
                $num = $result->rowCount();
                if ($num==0)
                {echo '<h2>Записей нет</h2>'; }
                else
                {
                    echo '<h2>Список товаров</h2><br>';
//строим таблицу, в которую будем выводить записи
```

Проблема в этом месте

```
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        $num = $result->rowCount();
```

Comment: вы используете PDO?

Comment: @midnightelf18 да

Comment: join'ы лучше использовать для таких запросов (хотя сам запрос ошибок не содержит)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка может быть в чем угодно, от ошибки в запросе SQL до ошибки подключения. Поэтому включите вывод ошибок для запросов PDO, так он точно скажет вам в чем дело

```php
$connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```